# How to parse and display the content of an Ixml object using IXML

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I am having difficult parsing the xml _file below using Ixml:

```
>>_file= "qv.xml"
```

file content:

```
<document reference="suspicious-document00500.txt">
  <feature name="plagiarism" type="artificial" obfuscation="none" this_offset="128" this_length="2503" source_reference="source-document00500.txt" source_offset="138339" source_length="2503"/>
  <feature name="plagiarism" type="artificial" obfuscation="none" this_offset="8593" this_length="1582" source_reference="source-document00500.txt" source_offset="49473" source_length="1582"/>
</document>
```

Here is my attempt:

```
>>from lxml.etree import XMLParser, parse
>>parsefile = parse(_file)

>>print parsefile

Output: <lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x000000000642E788>
```

The output is the location of the ixml object, while I am after the actual file content ie

```
Desired output={'document reference'="suspicious-document00500.txt", 'this_offset': '128', 'obfuscation': 'none', 'source_length': '2503', 'name': 'plagiarism', 'this_length': '2503', 'source_reference': 'source-document00500.txt', 'source_offset': '138339', 'type': 'artificial'}
```

Any ideas on how to get the desired output? thanks.

Comment: could you add the contents of the xml file?

Comment: @user2963623, i have included the xml file content to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of getting the desired outputs:

```
from lxml import etree

def main():
    doc = etree.parse('qv.xml')
    root = doc.getroot()
    print root.attrib
    for item in root:
        print item.attrib

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
{'reference': 'suspicious-document00500.txt'}
{'this_offset': '128', 'obfuscation': 'none', 'source_length': '2503', 'name': 'plagiarism', 'this_length': '2503', 'source_reference': 'source-document00500.txt', 'source_offset': '138339', 'type': 'artificial'}
{'this_offset': '8593', 'obfuscation': 'none', 'source_length': '1582', 'name': 'plagiarism', 'this_length': '1582', 'source_reference': 'source-document00500.txt', 'source_offset': '49473', 'type': 'artificial'}
```

It works fine with the contents you gave.
You might want to read [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/web/etree-view.html)to see how `etree` represents `xml` objects.